# How to return and use an enum of Swift class types or methods

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

I'm building a simple state engine, where I want a collection of states that I can move between.

The way I'd like to go about this is to have an enumeration of states that are possible that also define the corresponding class that represents that state, so that I can construct the state dynamically if I decide to move to that state.

In the code below I've tried building an enum of State objects which works fine.  Where I get stuck is, how can I access the values of this enum as types that I can call a static constructor method from?  In the code below the error I get is that the attempt to call moveToState with an enum value does not represent the StartupStates type, which it seems to...

So the question is really, why does this not work, or what other way can I have an enum of class types and/or class level (static) methods to call a constructor from?

```
public enum StartupStates<State> {
case Start(StartState)
case DownloadFiles(DownloadFilesState)
 }

 public protocol State {
   var stateEngine : StateEngine {get set}
 }

public class StateEngine
{
    var currentState : State?
    public func moveToState(newState : StartupStates<State>)
    {
    }
}

public class StartState : BaseState
{
    func doStateTasks()
    {
        // Move to next state, downloading files
        // ERROR IS HERE: 
        // "Cannot convert file of type '(DownloadFileState)->StartupStates<...>' to expected argument type 'StartupStates<State>'"

        stateEngine.moveToState(StartupStates.DownloadFiles)
    }
}

public class DownloadFilesState : BaseState
{
}


public class BaseState : State {
    public var stateEngine : StateEngine

    required public init( stateEngine : StateEngine ) {
        self.stateEngine = stateEngine
    }

    public static func stateCreator(stateEngine : StateEngine) -> Self {
        return self.init( stateEngine: stateEngine )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## String Solution:

You may be able to use `NSClassFromString` to your advantage in this scenario. Consider the following example:

```
enum State: String {
    case StartState = "StartClass"
    case DownloadState = "DownloadClass"
    case BaseState = "BaseClass"

    var klass: AnyClass {
        return NSClassFromString(self.rawValue)!
    }
}
```

Let me know if this sort of solution is what you are looking for.

## Alternative Solution:

If you want to not depend on typing the string solutions then you'll need to have a simple switch statement for the class types:

```
class StartClass {}
class DownloadClass {}
class BaseClass {}

enum State {
    case StartState
    case DownloadState
    case BaseState

    var klass: AnyClass {
        switch self {
        case .StartState:
            return StartClass.self
        case .DownloadState:
            return DownloadClass.self
        case .BaseState:
            return BaseClass.self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought about that approach as well as I would have done something like that in ObjC, but I was hoping for a more strongly typed Swift solution without chance of messing up the state name in a way that would cause a runtime error.

Comment: The only other way would be to switch over the different states. I'll update the answer with the other option.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with that approach - at least the mapping between enum and class is in one place.  Of note is that I decided to change the factory method for making state instances to the more direct return type of State rather than Self:     public static func stateCreator(stateEngine : StateEngine) -> State

Comment: Actually, when declaring `enum State: String` you do not need to specify the string in the case definition - it's automatic.

Comment: Mundi, I actually found that the current compiler does require this for the raw values. Perhaps a different version does not but the one I'm running does enforce this.

Comment: Anyone know why this is downvoted? I'm happy to improve it if I know what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class StartState : BaseState {
    func doStateTasks() {        
        let download = DownloadFilesState(stateEngine: StateEngine())
        stateEngine.moveToState(.DownloadFiles(download))
   }
}
```

Because `DownloadFiles` enum need a `DownloadFilesState` object as define in enum.

Comment: That's close to what I want, but I don't like having to create the instance in that method, because I had also planned to have the engine do the instance creation so that it could handle injection of state engine metadata and also potentially reuse states for looping.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a completion handler instead of a class type?

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

class StartClass: MyProtocol {}
class DownloadClass: MyProtocol {}
class BaseClass: MyProtocol {}

enum State {
    case StartState
    case DownloadState
    case BaseState

    var completionHandler: () -> MyProtocol {
        switch self {
        case .StartState:
            return { return StartClass() }
        case .DownloadState:
            return { return DownloadClass() }
        case .BaseState:
            return { return BaseClass() }
        }
    }
}
```

Accessing the initialized class from enum value.

```
var myState: State = .StartState
myState.completionHandler { initializedStartClass in
    InitializedStartClass.methods....
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you'd use the completion handler, something like the "        stateEngine.moveToState(StartupStates.DownloadFiles)" line of code I had?

Comment: I would have better sample if I understood how you want to use the initialized class, but the code you have mentioned should not change, since it does not require a class to be initialized yet. On the other hand you can use the additional code added in the answer to acquire the initialized class for using any methods (or instances) of the class.

Comment: When stateEngine.moveToState(StartupStates.DownloadFiles) is called, I just want code associated that state to start executing.  That's pretty much the extent of the operation, a state is moved to, it executes, then the code decides (either code in the state, or code outside the state) what is the next state to move to.